# I am facing an issue in formatting a complex soap object in android

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Please if any one have experience in consuming WCF service from android

The format that I need

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService.Contracts">
   <v:Header/>
   <v:Body>
      <tem:Login>
         <tem:request>
            <web:UserID>0</web:UserID>
            <web:Password>1</web:Password>
            <web:UserName>admin</web:UserName>
         </tem:request>
      </tem:Login>
   </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

The format generated by my code

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
        <UserID i:type="d:string">0</UserID>
        <UserName i:type="d:string">admin</UserName>
        <Password i:type="d:string">1</Password>
    </Login>
</v:Body>
```

My code is following

1- LoginRequest Class

```
public class LoginRequest extends SoapObject implements KvmSerializable {

    private String mUserID;
    private String mUserName;
    private String mPassword;

    public LoginRequest() {

        super(AppConstants.NAMESPACE, AppConstants.METHOD_NAME_LOGIN);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return mUserID;
        case 1:
            return mUserName;
        case 2:
            return mPassword;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {

        return 3;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = AppConstants.REQUEST_PARAM_USER_ID;
            break;
        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = AppConstants.REQUEST_PARAM_USERNAME;
            break;
        case 2:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = AppConstants.REQUEST_PARAM_PASSWORD;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {

        if (value == null)
            value = "";

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            mUserID = value.toString();
            break;
        case 1:
            mUserName = value.toString();
            break;
        case 2:
            mPassword = value.toString();
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

2- Login Method

```
try {

                        LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest();
                        request.setProperty(0, "0");
                        request.setProperty(1, username);
                        request.setProperty(2, password);

                        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
                        envelope.dotNet = true;

                        envelope.addMapping("http://tempuri.org/", "Login", LoginRequest.class);

                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("my_service_url");
                        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                        androidHttpTransport.call("my_service_action", "Login"), envelope);

                        if (envelope.bodyIn != null) {

                            //LoginResponse response = (LoginResponse) envelope.bodyIn;
                        }

                        System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                        System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                        System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get as close to Your envelope as i can, but it's a bit tricky. What i done is correct structure and namespaces uris on tags, try this - maybe WS will accept such response:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
            <n0:request i:type="n0:request" xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">
                <n1:UserID i:type="d:string" xmlns:n1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService.Contracts">0</n1:UserID>
                <n2:UserName i:type="d:string" xmlns:n2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService.Contracts">nam</n2:UserName>
                <n3:Password i:type="d:string" xmlns:n3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService.Contracts">pas</n3:Password>
            </n0:request>
        </Login>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

I added namespaces to UserID, UserName and Password this way:

```
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "UserID";
        info.namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService.Contracts";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "UserName";
        info.namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService.Contracts";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Password";
        info.namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService.Contracts";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

and added outermost tag this way:

```
SoapObject request_main = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "Login");

LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest();
request.setProperty(0, "0");
request.setProperty(1, "nam");
request.setProperty(2, "pas");

request_main.addProperty("request", request);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 


 envelope.dotNet = true;
//here additional flag
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

envelope.addMapping("http://tempuri.org/", "request", LoginRequest.class);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request_main);
```

regards
Marcin

ps. Added implicitTypes=true to envelope object. This removes i:type attributes - especially i:type="n0:request".

Comment: Added implicitTypes=true to envelope object. This removes i:type attributes - especially i:type="n0:request". Try now if it do not worked.